# Font displayed as squares in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, fonts, ubuntu-gnome

I have installed on Ubuntu 20.04 recently. I can't use it since the fonts display only squares. I can't work properly unless I use the terminal for navigating my folders. I have tried all the solutions to related questions so far. But none of them seems to work.

Here is an image of my desktop:

[image: Here is an image of my desktop]

Answer (score 3):

You may need to rebuild the font cache. Fortunately, it’s not too difficult:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Remove the existing font cache:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.cache/fontconfig
   ```
3. Rebuild the cache:

   ```
   sudo fc-cache -r -v
   ```

This should resolve the issue for you

Comment: I tried but it did not work.

Comment: @oklm Have you  by any chance deleted fonts? And/or somehow changed your home and/or system folders permissions?